# fetch data from online xml

Tags: xml, rss

I want to fetch data from XMl File (BBC News RSS Feeds) and show it in my html page ... but I have a minor problem.I saved the XML RSS feeds File on my local server and its running fine but when i am trying to fetch the XML data online by placing a url its not working ... Thank you

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  var url = "bbc.xml";
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table><tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

the upper code is running Fine but when i placed URL For XML File to fetch data ... the page is not showing any data like this

```
var url = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml";
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

What i need to do ... help me

Comment: Have you checked the status of the response (i.e. `xmlhttp.status`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many websites need permissions for using ajax over him, if you don't have access how to administrator to modify the access of ajax of your website. Other choice is using php or other language for obtain xml file.
you can check this using the firefox complement "firebug" and run your application see your console during the execution

Comment: Thank you , yes you are correct its not remotely accessible remotely ... So I tried CORS-ORIGIN Request But thats also not working so What I need to do now ... Thank you